# Exit code is not bubbled up

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Outer.ps1:

```
& "$env:WINDIR\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '.\Inner.ps1'; Write-Host "BLOCK: $LastExitCode"; exit $LastExitCode"
Write-Host "OUTSIDE: $LastExitCode"
```

Inner.ps1:

```
exit 3
```

Executing `Outer.ps1` outputs:

```
BLOCK: 1
OUTSIDE: 1
```

What, why? Inner.ps1 clearly exited with exit code 3. What's the problem?

Note: If I change `Inner.ps1` to return `0`, I receive the following output:

```
BLOCK: 0
OUTSIDE: 0
```

Somehow, all other codes than 0 are defaulted to 1, why?

Comment: What happens when you remove the single quotes from `& '.\Inner.ps1'`? I dont think inner is being called. When I remove the single quotes it was working

Comment: Same result, however, it does not work anymore if Inner.ps1 would have spaces in the name.

Comment: Yeah.. was testing in ISE and I only got it to work when I ran Inner manually so I was ruining the test. Back to the drawing board

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have quoting problem:

```powershell
& "$env:WINDIR\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command '& ''.\Inner.ps1''; Write-Host "BLOCK: $LastExitCode"; exit $LastExitCode'
Write-Host "OUTSIDE: $LastExitCode"
```

Comment: I knew something looked awry but I could get it to work right. Learn something everyday.

Comment: To clarify for other readers: $LastExitCode had been replaced before even calling the script! You have to use single quotes here, in order to stop variable replacement!

Comment: More clarification: within single quotes you use single quotes by doubling them (`''.\Inner.ps1''`). Also: the quoting problem with `Write-Host` in the original command has not been a problem because PowerShell automatically concatenated the strings.